# My script is seems to be skipping the first line in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script that compares two files, line by line.

It seems to be skipping the first line in file1 unless the first line in file2 matches.

```
import sys
from sys import argv
import os

script, file1, file2 = argv

firstlist = []

try:
    with open(file1) as x:
        line = x.readline()
        while line:
            firstlist.append(line)
            line = x.readline().strip()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"\nError: Filename '{file1}' does not exist in current directory(don't forget to specify file/script type - .py, .txt, .csv...etc)")
    sys.exit(1)

secondlist = []

try:
    with open(file2) as y:
        line = y.readline()
        while line:
            secondlist.append(line)
            line = y.readline().strip()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"\nError: Filename '{file2}' does not exist in current directory(don't forget to specify file/script type - .py, .txt, .csv...etc)")
    sys.exit(1)

overlaplist = []

for elem in firstlist:
    if elem in secondlist:
        overlaplist.append(elem)

print(f"\n The following IPs have been added to csv file in {os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}:\n {','.join(overlaplist)}")

with open('return.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(overlaplist))
```

[xxx.144.189.62 in 1.txt does not get detected by the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISEzj.png)

If I move it off the first line it gets compared accordingly with 2.txt

thoughts please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current script is listing lines from file1 and returning those **which are also in file2**, is that really what you want it to do?

If so, this script works well for me:

```
import sys
from sys import argv
import os

_, file1, file2 = argv

def list_lines(file):
    try:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            return [line.strip() for line in f]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: Filename '{file}' does not exist")
        sys.exit(1)

list1 = list_lines(file1)
list2 = list_lines(file2)

overlaplist = [l for l in list1 if l in list2]

if not overlaplist:
    print('no ip added')
else:

    print(f"The following IPs have been added to csv file in {os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}:\n {', '.join(overlaplist)}")

    with open('return.csv', 'w+') as f:
        f.write("\n".join(overlaplist))
```

Comment: I usually use this script to find the difference with "not in", but I changed it slightly to get the common lines for a current task

Comment: ok, and is the script I proposed working? Because it seemed to be fine when I tried it

Comment: Yes your script works, thanks for that. At least I can keep working on my task :-) out of curiosity, any idea what the problem with my script is?

Comment: Yeah, that's just because you were not using `strip()` on the first line, leaving a trailing '\n' at the end of this line... Also, if this solution worked for you, think to mark the question as solved :)